# Create notification from command line in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications, action-center

I have a script that is associated with a keyboard shortcut, when I trigger the shortcut, I want a notification to appear confirming that the script executed.

How do I create a notification from inside a script?

**EDIT**

On Linux, I used to do `command && notify-send "My message"`

Comment: echo msgbox "the message that you want" > "%temp%\popup.vbs" 

wscript.exe "%temp%\popup.vbs"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PowerShell you can run (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42605444/5518385)):

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"Script Completed!","Your script ran succesfully!",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

Or this (from [here](https://gist.github.com/altrive/72594b8427b2fff16431)):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$notificationTitle = "Notification: Your script has been completed successfully"
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
$template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText01)
$toastXml = [xml] $template.GetXml()
$toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text").AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationTitle)) > $null
$xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($toastXml.OuterXml)
$toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)
$toast.Tag = "Test1"
$toast.Group = "Test2"
$toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddSeconds(5)
$notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("Script Completed!")
$notifier.Show($toast);
```

Comment: Is there a way to auto clear it after a few seconds?

Comment: Also, I don't want an icon to show in the taskbar, notification only.

Comment: @daka, added 2nd method that has does show in the taskbar and has an expireing-seconds parts

Comment: Regarding the second way, removing `Notification:` from `$notificationTitle` makes it stop working, why?

Comment: @daka works for me (see https://i.imgur.com/AzjMFwu.png). Did you make sure to leave the opening quotes before it?

Comment: Yep I did, very weird.

Comment: To clear it after a few seconds, `Start-Sleep` then `.Dispose()`.

Comment: @YisroelTech any way to keep it from disappearing? I'm trying to work on some tasks WHILE a notif is open.
Perhaps making it manual close only by the "X" button?

Comment: @BenRacicot I do not believe so